# Hibernate fetching object linked to current user

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, paging

I'm currently a little blocked with this and I can't see it clearly.

So I hope one of you have good idea's to help me.

The important code at the moment :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_NOTA_RECIPIENT")
public class NotaRecipient extends PersistentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NOTA_RECIPIENT_SID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "STATUS", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.NEW;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "NOTA_SID", referencedColumnName = "NOTA_SID", nullable = false)
    private Nota nota;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATOR_OFFICE_SID", referencedColumnName = "OFFICE_SID", nullable = false)
    private Office creator;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "notaRecipient")
    private Set<FollowUp> followUps;

    ...
}
```

Now, actually I don't want to load all the `FollowUp` who are in the DB but just the one of the current user.
But the problem is that I want to include the FollowUp so I can do database paging query.
We use hibernate, Spring Data and Query DSL with BooleanBuilder to "refine" our search.

I was thinking of using `@Formula` but this need to be a constant String so I can't include current userId in that.

Second solution could be setting the FollowUp as `@Transient` and fetch it myself in the DB and set it in mine service.
Problem here is that I can't use it as filter then or ordering by it.

`@Formula` doesn't have so much documentation, so is it possible to make a `@Transient` user and use that in the `@Formula`?

I asked some colleagues but they couldn't help me.

So then it's the time for asking here.
I can get the current user in the API, so that's no problem.

Anybody have alternative solutions?

Comment: How  do you detect the 'current user'?

Comment: I fetch it by `SecurityUtil.getUser()` who will fetch it from the `SecurityContextHolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a mapping with expression

```
@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT f.id 
                                              FROM follow_up_table f 
                                              WHERE f.nota_id=id
                                              and f.user_id={USER_ID})", 
 referencedColumnName="...")
```

And then add hibernate interceptor (see [the example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)) and change the SQL on fly replacing {USER_ID} with real value in the

```
/**
 * Called when sql string is being prepared. 
 * @param sql sql to be prepared
 * @return original or modified sql
 */
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql);
```

Comment: I'm almost there, just need to get the interceptor to work with spring data (and no spring boot)

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/2323-how-to-use-an-hibernate-interceptor-with-spring

Comment: I'll come later back, this should normally work so I accepted it.  Just our base framework is struggling with me atm, but already thanks